# How does OpenNLP calculate the false negatives when using the Sentence Detector Evaluation Tools?

Tags: java, nlp, information-retrieval, opennlp

I have found part of code of OpenNLP which shows me how to calculate the True Positive Value. I was wondering how does the false negative value been calculated when using OpenNLP Sentence Evaluation Tools. In another word, what does the Precision, Recall and F-Measure mean in terms of evaluation tool was used? Explain with examples would be wonderful.
(Sorry for my stupid question, i am totally new to NLP...)

```
public static int countTruePositives(final Object[] references, final Object[] predictions) {



List<Object> predListSpans = new ArrayList<Object>(predictions.length);
Collections.addAll(predListSpans, predictions);
int truePositives = 0;
Object matchedItem = null;

for (int referenceIndex = 0; referenceIndex < references.length; referenceIndex++) {
  Object referenceName = references[referenceIndex];

  for (int predIndex = 0; predIndex < predListSpans.size(); predIndex++) {

    if (referenceName.equals(predListSpans.get(predIndex))) {
      matchedItem = predListSpans.get(predIndex);
      truePositives++;
    }
  }
  if (matchedItem != null) {
    predListSpans.remove(matchedItem);
  }
}
return truePositives;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here. It shall help you to understand things.

Link: http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/util/eval/FMeasure.html